# delete unnecessary settings from GPO

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016, powershell-v5.0

I want to delete some unnecessary settings from one GPO. I use windows server 2016, and i have unnecessary registry settings which i don't want to appear in my GPO.
It is possible to perform this action.I have try to edit this policy (right click->edit gpo under computer configuration-> preferences->windows settings-> registry ) and i have tried to set the unnecessary settings to DELETE, but the initial settings is still there.
Exist another possibility to perform this action.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to do a GUI error.

You just right click and delete the settings you no longer want.

If you double click the registry setting, and you set the setting to delete or remove, it will remove those registry settings from the computer you target your GPO to.

Comment: Hello, i can't do the actions suggested by you because i don't see any registry settings when i try to access this path: "gpo->edit->preferences-windows settings->registry" i don't have any settings there (but in my gpo i can see these settings)

Answer (score 0):

The settings don't take effect the moment you edit the GPO on the Domain Controller.

Reboot the client and then your registry should be updated.